# How to change the color from state by its index number in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to change the color of my border color of my cardItem. but when i clicking on it my all cardItem bordercolor  is changing, not the one which I am selecting.

Hers my code:

```
 selectApp = (index, newSelected) => {
    let newArr = this.state.userData.appearance.split(',');
    newArr = [...this.state.cards];

    newArr[index].selected = newSelected;

    
    this.setState({
      cards: newArr,
      
      bcolor0: 'yellow',
      bwidth0: 3,
    });
  };
```

CardItem:

```
 <CardItem
                            button
                            onPress={() =>
                              this.selectApp(index, !item.selected)
                            }
                            cardBody
                            style={{
                              backgroundColor: '#549bc4',
                              borderColor: this.state.bcolor0,
                              borderWidth: this.state.bwidth0,
                              marginRight: 'auto',
                              marginLeft: 'auto',
                            }}>
```

Comment: Your new array is based on `this.state.userData`, but your `setState` call isn't changing that.

Comment: ohh sorry..i meant border color

Comment: Okay then, your state only contains a single border color, not an array. You need an array.

Comment: `  cards: [
        {
          value: 0,
          text: 'H',
          image: require('../assets/hi.png'),
          borderC: 'purple',
          borderW: 3,
          selected: false,
        },
        {
          value: 1,
          text: 'N',
          image: require('../assets/n.png'),
          selected: false,
          borderC: 'purple',
          borderW: 3,
        },`
]


it is like that

Comment: You are already using an array for your other card properties, but your borderColor is still a single value directly in state. You have everything you need to turn borderC into a per-card state. If you wrote the code you've posted here, you already know how to do this.

Comment: can u pls edit my code. I am stuck here :(

Comment: Did you write the code in your question?

Comment: How can I do the same, Can u pls write code of that?

Comment: create a codesandbox and provide the link here,

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, as @Chris G suggested on comment, when you call `selectApp` you set `bcolor0: 'yellow'`. I suppose that all your `CardItem`s have in style `borderColor: this.state.bcolor0,`. So, when you call `selectApp` you are setting all the cards borderColor to yellow.

To resolve this, you have to do something like:

```
state: {
  ...
  bcolor0: []   // an array of border colors
}
selectApp = (index, newSelected) => {
    let newArr = this.state.userData.appearance.split(',');
    newArr = [...this.state.cards];

    newArr[index].selected = newSelected;

    // here I'm creating an array with the same length of newArr (supposing that you have newArr.length cards to show) 
    let new_boder_color = new Array(newArr.length).fill('white');
    new_boder_color[index] = 'yellow';
    this.setState({
      cards: newArr,
      
      bcolor0: new_boder_color,
      bwidth0: 3,
    });
  };
```

Then in your `CardItem`:

```
<CardItem
                            button
                            onPress={() =>
                              this.selectApp(index, !item.selected)
                            }
                            cardBody
                            style={{
                              backgroundColor: '#549bc4',
                              borderColor: this.state.bcolor0[index],
                              borderWidth: this.state.bwidth0,
                              marginRight: 'auto',
                              marginLeft: 'auto',
                            }}>
```

In this way you are setting to yellow only the borderColor of the selected card. I'd like to be more precise, but code you posted is not complete and it's a little bit tricky write precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just done that by doing minor changes in my Carditem style property.

borderColor:
item.selected === true ? 'purple' : '',
borderWidth: item.selected === true ? 3 : 0,